# Дополнить до десяти: что не так с алгоритмом?

Tags: c#

Задание состоит, собственно в этом, мои попытки прикреплены ниже, помогите, пожалуйста. В данный момент у меня просто постепенно число удаляется, не могу понять как изменить цифру, при это сохранив остальные.

Напишите функцию static int UpToTen (int n), которая по данному натуральному
числу n возвращает число, полученное из n следующим образом: для каждой цифры i
числа n в новом числе ставится цифра (10-i), цифра 0 остается без изменений (например,
при вводе 1079 программа выводит 9031).

```
static void UpToTen(int n)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            while (n > 0)
            {
                if (n % 10 != 0)
                {
                    int i = n % 10;
                    temp = (10 - i) + (n - i);
                }
                n /= 10;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Полученный результат = " + temp);
        }
```

Comment: У вас две ошибки. Вы не умножаете temp на 10 и у вас нули не обрабатываются.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, как в данном случае обработать 0, что-то прибавить нужно?

Comment: Это можно обработать двумя вариантами. Первый есть у вас - через if, вам нужно дописать ветку else, в которой указать иную формулу для temp. Второй вариант вообще убрать if и всегда брать 10 - i но эта формула нуждается в коррекции: надо брать остаток по модулю 10, это для нуля даст верный ответ.

Comment: Понимаю, что нужно написать ветку else, но не совсем понимаю что именно мне нужно писать туда

Comment: @l1can static int UpToTen(int n) => int.Parse(new String(n.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(s => s == '0' ? '0' : (10 - byte.Parse(s.ToString())).ToString()[0]).ToArray())); Console.WriteLine(UpToTen(1079)); //9031

Comment: @Blackmeser много лишнего, снова, `int.Parse(string.Concat(n.ToString().Select(d => d == '0' ? d : (char)(106 - d))))`

Comment: @aepot я и забыл что существует смещение, по которому из чара можно достать цифру =)

Comment: @Blackmeser именно, еще перегнули с `ToCharArray` - строка итерируется как массив символов из коробки. Если вам не требуется изменять полученный массив, то и смысла его создавать нет.

Comment: @aepot ``int.Parse(string.Concat((""+n).Select(d => d == '0' ? d : (char)(106 - d))))`` - ещё мельче =)

Comment: @Blackmeser `$"{n}"` тогда уж.

Comment: @aepot сдаюсь, дальше уменьшать некуда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почти верно написали логику, вам только не хватило коэффициента, на который надо умножать полученную цифру. Ну и с нулями ввело вас в заблуждение, вы решили добавить условие, а можно было просто взять остаток от деления на 10.

Еще одна ошибка в том, что сигнатура метода не соответствует той, что указана в задаче, у вас `void UpToTen(int n)` а должно быть `int UpToTen(int n)`. Будьте внимательны.

```cs
static int UpToTen(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    int k = 1;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        result += (10 - n % 10) % 10 * k;
        n /= 10;
        k *= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Проверяем

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Полученный результат = " + UpToTen(1079));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Полученный результат = 9031
```

---

Бонус - решение через строки-символы

```cs
static int UpToTen(int n)
{
    return int.Parse(string.Concat(n.ToString().Select(d => d == '0' ? d : (char)(10 - d + '0' + '0'))));
}
```

Оно медленнее и ресурсозатратнее, чем математическое, я просто решил показать, что оно существует и работает. Кстати, фрагмент `(char)(10 - d + '0' + '0')` можно записать как `(char)(106 - d)`.

Comment: @AK, `i` один раз всего используется - его можно вообще выбросить :)

Comment: @Grundy выбросил, спасибо